# Android license check with "Background Data" turned off

Tags: android, android-lvl

It looks like when "Backround Data" is turned off on device, the license can't be checked...

```
Settings > Accounts & Sync > Background Data
```

I get such error from ILicensingService:

```
ERROR_CONTACTING_SERVER "Error contacting licensing server. Check your network connection.
```

Any idea how to bypass this settings, and force the license check?

Comment: Accounts Sync is required by market app, which is the dedicate app that process license check. I doubt if it is doable.

Comment: Are you experiencing this on newer Android versions? Because on older versions it appears to work to work. Connectivity policies have changed recently.

Answer (score 0):

If you are always catching "Error contacting licensing server." check the licence compiling. When i used jar file as "External Jar file" at eclipse menu "Project Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries", new version of the same aplication not worked. But When i compiling my project and licence project together, all works fine. It was tested on Android API 10.

So, try to load licence library from "Project Properties > Android > Library (tab) > Add...".